# Free fall time after being accelerated

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, relative-motion

> An elevator car whose floor-to-ceiling distance is equal to $2.7m$ starts ascending with constant acceleration $1.2 m/s^2$; $2.0 s$ after the start a bolt begins falling from the ceiling of the car. Find the bolt's free fall time.

$l=2.7m$ and $w=1.2m/s^2$ I am trying to solve using the absolute frame of reference.

This is my wrong attempt, the bolt's equation for $t\geq 2s$ would be $y_b(t)=-\frac{1}{2}g(t-2)^2+e(2)+l$ where $e(t)=\frac{1}{2}wt^2$ the position of the elevator's floor in the absolute frame of reference.

$d(t)=y_b(t)-e(t)=-\frac{1}{2}(w+g)t^2+2gt+2(w-g)+l$ the distance between the bolt and the elevator for $t\geq 2s$.

I get $\Delta=4g^2+(2g+2w)(2w-2g+l)$ and so $t=\frac{-2g\pm\sqrt{4g^2+(2g+2w)(2w-2g+l)}}{-(g+w)}$ which yields a wrong answer.

My mistake is probably in the bolt's position equation, I don't see how it's wrong though.

The correct answer is $0.7s$.

**EDIT:**
I didn't take into account the fact that the bolt would have a velocity when it's set free. After editing my equations, however, I still get a wrong result (two seconds later than it should be).
Here's what I did :
$$y_b(t)=-\frac{1}{2}g(t-2)^2+2w(t-2)+(l+2w) \text{ for }t\geq2s$$
$$e(t)=\frac{1}{2}wt^2$$
$$\begin{align*}
d(t)&=y_b(t)-e(t)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}g(t^2-4t+4)-\frac{1}{2}wt^2+2wt+(-4w+l+2w)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+2gt-2g-\frac{1}{2}wt^2+2wt+(l-2w)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}(g+w)t^2+2(g+w)t+(l-2w-2g)
\end{align*}$$
We have then :
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta &=4(g+w)^2+2(g+w)(l-2w-2g)\\
&=2(g+w)[2(g+w)+l-2w-2g]\\
&=2l(g+w)
\end{align*}$$
Finally :
$$\begin{align*}
t&=\frac{-2(g+w)\pm\sqrt{2l(g+w)}}{-(g+w)}\\
&=2\mp\sqrt{\frac{2l}{w+g}}
\end{align*}$$
Does someone know where I have gone wrong?

**EDIT 2:**
Actually, my EDIT solution is correct, I just need to subtract 2 from it. I thought I am looking for the time at which the bolt makes contact with the floor, but that's incorrect, I am looking for the duration.

Comment: did you include the 9.8 meters per second per second the bolt would fall if there were no elevator

Comment: A hint: Get into the reference frame of the elevator and stay in that reference frame.  In that reference frame, g=-11m/s^2, and the falling bolt starts with an initial velocity of 0 m/s.

Comment: @DavidWhite considering the elevator's frame of reference, it becomes easy; $$-\frac{1}{2}(w+g)t^2+l=0\implies t=\sqrt{\frac{2l}{w+g}}$$but I would like to do it using the absolute frame of reference, I guess I should precise that.

Comment: @Luyw, with that being the case, it would help if you changed the title of your question.

Comment: @DavidWhite can you please check my edit?

Comment: @Luyw The bolt does not have an initial velocity when set free in the frame of reference of the elevator. Only in a fixed frame of reference outside the elevator. See point 4 of my answer. You are overcomplicating the problem. A single equation using answers to my  questions can solve the problem. Look at my 4 points and let me know which one you are having difficulty with.

Comment: @BobD thank you, however the equation I set was for the bolt in the absolute frame of reference, isn't it correct that way? oh and see what I responded to David, I am trying to solve the problem using the main frame of reference.

Comment: @Luyw The difficulty may lie in how are you defining the "absolute or main frame of reference".  How are you defining it?

Comment: @BobD $y$-axis, the elevator's floor starts at $0$ and ceiling at $l$, and thus the bolt at $l$ also.

Comment: and the elevator's frame is such as the floor is $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Luyw That sounds like the frame of reference of the elevator. Can you not see that in the frame of reference of the elevator that the downward acceleration of the bolt is -9.8 - 1.2, or -11.0 as per David White's hint?

Comment: I do I do! Check out the earlier comments, I have solved the question using the elevator's frame. I am trying, though, to express both the elevator's and the bolt's equation of motion in the absolute frame, then figure out the time from the distance formula.

Comment: do you see a problem in the equations I have added in the edit?

Comment: @Luyw I still don't know what you mean by the "absolute frame". Sorry.

Comment: @BobD the ground. And, actually, my solution is correct, I just need to subtract 2 from it. I thought I am looking for the time at which the bolt makes contact with the floor, but that's incorrect, I am looking for the duration.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Luyw Now I see. You should have been looking at elapsed time, right?

Comment: @BobD yes that's it!

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't provide complete answers to homework and exercise questions, only guidance. So consider the following in your calculations:

1. With respect to a fixed frame of reference outside the elevator, once the bolt becomes free of the ceiling what downward acceleration does it experience?
2. At the same time with respect to a fixed frame of reference outside the elevator, what is the upward acceleration of the elevator?
3. Given 1 and 2, what is the acceleration of the bolt with respect to the frame of reference of the elevator?
4. In the frame of reference of the elevator, what will be the initial velocity of the bolt when it is released from the ceiling?

Having answered the above you should be able to apply the kinematic equation relating distance traveled vs acceleration and time.

Hope this helps.